# Trying to fix a If...End If block

Tags: vba, ms-access

I get this compile error:

> Block If without End If

Here is my code that I am working with

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.txtusername) Then
        'MsgBox "Please enter Username", vbInformation, "Username Required"
    If IsNull(Me.txtpassword) Then
        'MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password Required"
    Else
        'processs the job
        If (IsNull(DLookup("[username]", "tbllogin info", "[username] ='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "' And password = '" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'"))) Then
            MsgBox "login unsucessful"
        End If

        'MsgBox "Login Succeddful"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "s-1 page"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using two if's in a row, instead you should use ElseIf.

```
If IsNull(Me.txtusername) Then
    'MsgBox "Please enter Username", vbInformation, "Username Required"
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtpassword) Then
    'MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password Required"
Else
    'processs the job
    If (IsNull(DLookup("[username]", "tbllogin info", "[username] ='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "' And password = '" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'"))) Then
    MsgBox "login unsucessful"
    End if
End If
```

Comment: You still have two block Ifs with only one End If.

Comment: woops, missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

You have three `If ... Then` lines, but only close one of them. You should join them into one construct with `ElseIf`:

Fix like this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.txtusername) Then
        'MsgBox "Please enter Username", vbInformation, "Username Required"
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtpassword) Then
        'MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password Required"
    ElseIf IsNull(DLookup("[username]", "tbllogin info", "[username] ='" & Me.txtusername.Value & "' And password = '" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'")) Then
        MsgBox "login unsuccessful"
    Else
        'MsgBox "Login successful"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "s-1 page"
    End If
End Sub
```